# Move an entity to another list

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to move an entity (JPA) from one list to another list.

The problem is that the entity gets deleted instead of being moved (in the database).

The model (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Item> items;

    public Group() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long id;
    private Group group;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The move operation is performed this way:

```
oldGroup.getItems().remove(item);
item.setGroup(newGroup);
newGroup.getItems().add(item);
```

Debugging shows that the lists are correctly updated but JPA is somehow unable to detect that the entity is used somewhere else and only cares about the  `CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval = true`.

Note: it works when moving an entity from the first group to the second group but not the opposite.

Comment: `orphanRemoval = true`means: if the entity is removed from the list, delete it. So it's precisely what you do not want to happen.

Comment: @JBNizet: if I remove `orphanRemoval = true` then I'll have to manually `remove()` each `Item` when I want to do so. Now I can just change the `Group` and `commit()`.

Comment: Have you tried not performing the `remove`/`add(item)` and only doing `item.setGroup(newGroup)`?

Comment: @DidierL that correctly updates the database but it leaves you with inconsistency in your objects since the list wasn't updated. The `Group` would would then need to be reloaded from the database to correct that.

Comment: I'm afraid it will be the price to pay if you want to keep the orphan removal.

Comment: @DidierL: the price is too steep as the `Groups` aren't committed right away and need to be displayed in a GUI so reloading the data doesn't even help for the GUI? only the model, and the GUI would need a good amount of workaround to fix it. You can always post your solution as an answer and we'll see if others like this over removing the `orphanRemoval = true`. @JBNizet: I went with the removal of `orphanRemoval = true`. I'm removing the `Items` manually. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: you can use session.refresh(object) to refresh your entity without triggering the delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orphanRemoval = true` means: if the entity is removed from the list, delete it. So it's precisely what you do not want to happen.

So just remove that attribute from your annotation (or set it to false).

Comment: Note: this solves the issue but complicates things as you'll need to delete the orphans yourself since JPA no longer does that for you (e.g. when you remove an `Item` from a `Group` you'll need to `entityManager.remove(item)` before you commit).

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of `OneToMany`:

```
/**
 * (Optional) Whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have
 * been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to
 * those entities.
 * @since Java Persistence 2.0
 */
boolean orphanRemoval() default false;
```

So I'm afraid that as soon as you remove the entity from the relationship, it is scheduled to be removed.

If you want to keep the `orphanRemoval` and avoid this issue, you could simply do the change on the `Item` side without altering the collection:

```
item.setGroup(newGroup);
```

without `getItems().remove`/`add(item)`.

If you really need to update the collection, you might `detach` the `oldGroup` before performing the change in the collection.

Notice though that if you are in the context of a web app, this is usually not a problem if your URL's are RESTful:

1. the client sends a `POST` to perform the change;
2. the server performs the change and replies with a redirect;
3. the client follows the redirect, which reloads the entity from database.